# Image is not loading in <img> tag with ftp url

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to show the user's photo in my ionic/cordova application using the img tag as follows,

```
 <img src="ftp://10.132.21.100/PatientPhoto/Temp_emp.jpg" alt="no image"/>
```

The image is not getting displayed in the APP (failed to load the resource error). But I can view the image if I enter the same URL(ftp://10.132.21.100/PatientPhoto/Temp_emp.jpg) in my android mobile browser. I am running the debug build, so I guess it is not a permission issue. I have done white listing by adding the below line in the config.xml file,

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

I tried adding below lines too without any success,

```
<allow-intent href="ftp://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="ftp://*/*" />
```

Also added Content-Security-Policy to the html file as follows, still facing the same issue.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

It is working if I a use http URL for img src. The images are stored in the ftp server, so I can't use http URL. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: @Neotrixs, added the code

Comment: I suggest you to that better to change "FTP" to "HTTP" and one more thing, please give permission of URL in config file.

Comment: The URL should be in quote marks.  Some browsers might let that slide, but your app might not be so forgiving.

Comment: You got this issue in android or ios?

Comment: @NiRmaL I got the issue in android & I have not tested it in iOS

Comment: Most likely not rated but you are missing a / at the end … it should be <img …. />

Comment: @frlan it is not working even after adding '/' at the end

Comment: Could you give us a working ftp url of the image (or any image)?

Comment: Is that a real url? I get time out

Comment: failed to load the resource error with what reason?

Comment: Are you working with Ionic 2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [cordova whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) and to config your `config.xml` file.

Please add the following tag: `<allow-intent href="ftp://*/*" />`

or if you want to allow everything: `<access origin="*">`

Comment: same issue even after adding <access origin="*"> to the config.xml file

Answer (score 2):

You can try to modify your src attribute like this:

```
 <img src="ftp://yourusername:yourpassword@10.132.21.100/PatientPhoto/Temp_emp.jpg"/>
```

it will work but you'd be giving everyone your ftp password.do not use this on a live website

Comment: You could create an anonymous/guest account that takes any password

Answer (score 1):

Have you got a Content Security Policy header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" />
```

You'll need this on the page(s) that the image is displayed on.

See the following link for pointers: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy

Comment: yes.. I added Content-Security-Policy. still same issue

Comment: Try adding img-src * to your CSP

Comment: i tried it, still it is not working.    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src * ">

Answer (score 0):

< img src="ftp://10.132.21.100/PatientPhoto/Temp_emp.jpg">

Give src between  " " and  Make sure your server is running

Comment: same issue with quotes ("") also

Comment: wondering if you ever solved this problem.  I have a similar issue.  Using code like the one mentioned above `<img src="ftp://yourusername:yourpassword@10.132.21.100/PatientPhoto/Temp_emp.jpg"/>`  Works for me in any browser except firefox.  I'm wondering if it's possible to make it work in firefox.   I did get it to work by using an iframe though.